# Is a CDS spread a spread in a typical sense

Tags: cds, credit

I have a basic question that's causing me some confusion. I see discussion of a "CDS spread," defined as the cost of protection. Are these the same as a bid-ask spread? Is there any relation between the two, if not? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding the terminology, there is no relation between CDS spread and bid/ask spread. The term spread in this sense refers to the related difference (spread) of the effective (credit risky) interest rate and the "risk free" rate (also see "credit spread").

Comment: Indeed, the CDS quote itself might have a bid-ask spread. For example, a market maker might be offering to sell CDS protection at 165 (ask) but to buy the same protection at only 160 (bid).